# How can I use cache only for anonymous users on Django?

Tags: django, caching

How can I show cached pages only to users not logged in Django 1.7?

Answer (score 0):

This method may not be the cleanest, but imho it's the easiest and it does not require any code except this snippet in your template:

```
{% with cache_timeout=request.user.is_authenticated|yesno:"0,300" %}
    {% load cache %}
    {% cache cache_timeout cache_identifier request.user.is_authenticated %}
        Insert content to cache here.
    {% endcache %}
{% endwith %}
```

You only have to adjust `cache_timeout` and `cache_identifier`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't have it very clear. I have a web site with topbar where you can see notifications and some menu options when you are logged in, but the URL does not change if you're logged in or not, so if a cache the page logged in, when I access to the same url not logged in I see the topbar with the options for the logged user who accessed before, any suggestion?. Thanks